# Running groovy scripts with matlab

Tags: matlab, groovy

I wrote a groovy script that I need to execute on matlab. I added the groovy-all.jar file to matlab's JavaClassPath, and I'm able to run a few commands, such as adding jars to groovy ClassPath by creating a groovy console object.

```
javaaddpath('C:\Users\rx49\Desktop\DoseWatch\QC_Project\Script_QA_images\groovy-all-2.4.7.jar');
javaaddpath('C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91\lib\rt.jar');
console=groovy.ui.Console();
pth='C:\Users\rx49\Desktop\DoseWatch\QC_Project\Script_QA_images\file.groovy';
script = javaObject('java.io.File', pth)
console.loadScriptFile(script);
```

THe console.loadScriptFile function only take as argument a java.io.File object. So I created one through the matlab javaObject function. When I execute the code below, matlab sends me the following error :

??? Java exception occurred:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method edt() on null object

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:57)

at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)

at groovy.ui.Console.loadScriptFile(Console.groovy:649)
```

Error in ==> run_script at 7
console.loadScriptFile(script);

Comment: http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/using-groovy-in-matlab ?

Comment: This one involves to create a jar file containing the methods in the groovy file, right ?

Comment: I tried to use this API : http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/ui/Console.html

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying, how you're doing it, or what error you're getting... getting help it's going to be tricky under these circumstances

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to be precise.

Comment: I first opened a console object : console = groovy.ui.Console(). Then I
 try to use methods of this object (described on the link of the API), such as console.addpathJar, allowing to add jar files to the groovy ClassPath.

Comment: Things get tricky when I try to run a groovy file with this console : I tried to load the groovy file with console.loadfile(), but it only take a File object as an input. First, I would like to know if there is a way to create a File object from the groovy file (by giving the path to the file as input e.g.). Then I don't know how does the runScript function work, the documentation I found isn't very explicit, so maybe if you have any clue about that...

Comment: Can you edit your question to put all the info in? Comments are awful for code

Comment: Done. I figured out how to create the File object, and updated my question.

Comment: Why are you trying to show the Groovy Console?

Comment: I am not, I'm just trying to use one of its function to run a groovy script. But the code I put in the question doesn't display the groovy console.

Comment: Ahhh, so you just want to run the groovy?

Comment: Can you put the groovy script in the question?

Comment: My company doesn't allow me to share the groovy code, but it runs on the console, I just need to get it running on matlab

Comment: No idea if it will work, but I've come up with a stab at what the answer should look like?

Comment: The script returns a matrix of doubles

Comment: Try adding `matrix =` to the last line of the matlab code (see below)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work, I don't have Matlab, or your script, but it feels like you should be able to do:

```
javaaddpath('C:\Users\rx49\Desktop\DoseWatch\QC_Project\Script_QA_images\groovy-all-2.4.7.jar');
pth='C:\Users\rx49\Desktop\DoseWatch\QC_Project\Script_QA_images\file.groovy';
shell = groovy.lang.GroovyShell();
matrix = shell.run(javaObject('java.io.File', pth));
```